# How to get Firebase custom email handler using dynamic link to work with Flutter web app

Tags: flutter, firebase, deep-linking, firebase-dynamic-links

I have a Flutter mobile & web app.

**What I want**
I want a dynamic link setup for my Firebase password-reset & email-verification custom email handlers that when clicked on mobile with the app installed will take the user to the appropiate screen to handle it. When clicked on desktop I want to take the user to the web app at a specific screen to handle it `https://myWebApp.io/reset-password`.

**What I've Tried**
I currently have a dynamic link setup that correctly takes the user into the mobile app if it's installed and takes them to the correct screen. However when clicked on desktop it takes the user to the currect web app but not the screen I need it to.

When the user taps on forgot password in the app, I call a firebase function that will create the forgot password email link using the dynamic link I created and then send it inside an email.

```
    const actionCodeSettings = {
        // URL you want to redirect back to. The domain (www.example.com) for
        // this URL must be whitelisted in the Firebase Console.
        url: 'https://myWebApp.io/reset-password',
        // This must be true for email link sign-in.
        handleCodeInApp: true,
        iOS: {
            bundleId: 'com.company.myApp',
        },
        android: {
            packageName: 'com.company.my_app',
            installApp: true,
        },
        // FDL custom domain.
        dynamicLinkDomain: 'myWebApp.io',
    };
    const link = await getAuth().generatePasswordResetLink(userEmail, actionCodeSettings);
```

I have a dynamic link setup under that domain in the firebase console and made it different so there is no conflict with the hosting domain name.

URL Prefix - https://myWebApp.io/links

Dynamic Link Configuration

```
 Deep Link - https://myWebApp.io/reset-password
 Short Dynamic Link (URL) - https://myWebApp.io/links/29hQ
```

I also have my Flutter web app Firebase config setup to treat the URL with `/links` as a dynamic link

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "source": ".",
    "site": "my-web-app",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "frameworksBackend": {
      "region": "us-central1"
    },
    "appAssociation": "AUTO",
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      },
      {
        "source": "/links/**",
        "dynamicLinks": true
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I'm having a really hard time understanding how all of this works together and is very likely the cause of my issues. I don't know why the dynamic link is not going to the correct url for the web app. When it gets generated it looks like this.

```
https://myWebApp.io/?link=https://myWebApp.io/links/29hQ?apiKey%APIKEY%26continueUrl%3Dhttps://myWebApp.io/reset-password%26lang%3Den&apn=com.company.my_app&amv&ibi=com.company.my-app&ifl=https://myWebApp.io/links/29hQ?apiKey%APIKEY%3DresetPassword%26oobCode%OOBCODE%26continueUrl%3Dhttps://myWebApp.io/reset-password%26lang%3Den
```

I want when a user clicks on that link on desktop to be taken to `https://myWebApp.io/reset-password` with the additional query parameters from a reset password email action handler. But instead they are taken to the root of my app.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, spent days digging through documentation and trial and error.

Comment: am not sure if you had figured out the issue but from some testing I have been doing trying to implement same, it takes you to the url you will declare in the Email templates at the Firebase Auth Console. From the url you shared, it looks like in your case, it will be https://myWebApp.io/ which I believe might be what you are experiencing.